# How to exclude dependency from project() dependency in Gradle

Tags: android, gradle

While using a project as a dependency, how can I exclude some jars selectively?

[image]

Here's what I tried:

```
compile project(':OneSDK') {
    exclude module: 'alipaySingle-20160223'
    exclude module: 'utdid4all-1.0.4'
}
```

I get this Error：

> Error:(93, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'exclude()' 
>   Possible causes
>
> - The project 'YoukeApplication' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method. Open Gradle wrapper file
> - The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin. Apply Gradle plugin

[image]

Comment: Please post the error message as text, not image.

Comment: Error:(93, 0) 
Gradle DSL method not found: 'exclude()'
Possible causesThe project 'YoukeApplication' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper 
file The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

Answer (score 2):

I would try a slightly different syntax:

```
compile(project(':OneSDK')) {
    exclude module: 'alipaySingle-20160223'
    exclude module: 'utdid4all-1.0.4'
}
```

Comment: Better than the previous, but there will be a compile time error

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':youke:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/alipay/android/app/IAlixPay$Stub$a.class

Comment: Back to the beginning of the error, the problem is not so treated?